# paginate MSword document text with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, ms-word

I've noticed when you cut and paste a word document into an htmt document (specifically, into a `contenteditable` div) it contains alot of meta data. What I'm interested in is a JavaScript function that would paginate this text into as many divs as their are "pages" in the word document.

If you are not familiar, here's an abbreviated version of what the word document looks like from viewing the source code:

```
<div contenteditable="true" >
 <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
 <o:AllowPNG/>
 </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
    </xml><![endif]-->
        <!--lots more junk until get to actual content which is here:-->
     <p class="Default">
        <b><span style="font-size:14.0pt;font-family:Arial;color:windowtext">
          &nbsp;I am the actual title of this work. <o:p></o:p></span>
        </b>
     </p>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that is possible without actually emulating the way that word renders the text.  To my understanding, the position of where new pages are is determined by how much content can fit on each page.  Unless you're looking for physical page breaks (which might be able to be located in this meta data) I'm not sure you can find where actual pages are divided.

**EDIT**

Since it seems to be using mostly HTML sort of stuff, it's possible you could write a Javascript solution which manipulates the DOM to do the rendering and height calculations.  It could do a kind of 'binary search' to figure out how many elements can fit on a given page.  When that amount of elements is found, it could place them and continue adding elements to following pages.

**EDIT AGAIN**

Here's a quick fiddle of what such an approach might look like:

http://jsfiddle.net/LukeGT/Vtdgh/2/

Note that this doesn't break paragraphs like a normal document should (it's a fairly complex process), and I haven't tested this much so there's bound to be bugs.  Think of this as a starting point.  You'll also have to remove all the non-HTML elements from the document yourself.  The script reads from the `#doc` div, and places `li`'s as pages in the `ul` at the bottom of the page.  Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, yeah the solution might be based on character count or some meta data tag, not sure...

Comment: hi @LukeGT, thanks for the further explanation, I think I understand conceptually, just not how the code would look, can you take a shot at that?